# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, audio, encoding, websocket, base64

I am writing an [asyncio web-sockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) app. I have my client and server who have exchanging the data in json format. Sometimes as a response to the client, server returns audio data. I encode that data in base64 and decode as utf-8. But when I send json with audio data the web-socket client can not decode that data and raise "UnicodeDecodeError"

That is how I send data from the server

```
. . . 

# audio_data is binary data from ".wav" file
response = {
    'status': 'success', 
    'data': base64.b64encode(audio_data).decode('UTF-8')
}
# send data throught socket
await websocket.send(json.dumps(response))

. . .
```

The code that receives send data (Here I got the error)

```
. . .

# Receive data from web-socket server
response = await websocket.recv()

. . .
```

The error that I receives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 674, in transfer_data
    message = yield from self.read_message()
  File ".../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 757, in read_message
    return frame.data.decode('utf-8') if text else frame.data
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 51872: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: UTF-8 is for encoded Unicode **text** - **binary** data is not text.

Comment: So what is the way to prepare audio binary data for being in json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your framework expects you to output `bytes`, thus:

```
await wbsocket.send(json.dumps(...).encode(...))
```

Couple of nits:

- `b64encode` can be decoded with "ascii" just as well as "utf-8" due to restricted character set of base64
- `json.dumps` by default escapes unicode, thus `.encode("utf-8")` and `.encode("ascii")` should produce same result
- `websockets` docs don't specify if input expects and output produces `str` or `bytes`...

Comment: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol.send .. apparently type flips what kind of websocket frame is being sent -- i.e. you could even send raw audio data if you wanted!